# Is not it possible to have an "empty|null" value assigned to a product field without necessarily inherit the value of the default language?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I'm facing a challenge with translations.

Basically there are several languages setup (en-GB, it-IT, pt-PT), but the default language is always German (de-DE).

```
en-GB: "This is a sample text."
de-DE: "Dies ist ein Beispieltext."
```

I'm cleaning up the English (en-GB) value and the German (de-DE) value shows up.

```
en-GB: ""
de-DE: "Dies ist ein Beispieltext."
```

That makes sense. That's what fallback is all about.

HOWEVER, here comes the problem. For many-many-many fields it doesn't make any sense to display German (de-DE) texts for the storefront customers... and client really needs that to be empty, not German. But of course, it keeps displaying German texts... even tho the field is empty on the English language.

**Question:** Is not it possible to have a "empty|null" value assigned to a product field without necessarily inherit the value of the default language?

Answer (score 1):

That would be the difference between using fields with or without the `translated` accessor.

Let's say you have a product description that has been written in the default language but is empty in the secondary language. The latter being the current language.

```
{{ page.product.translated.description }}
```

Since the translated field is used here, it will be the description written in the current language, if it exists. If it doesn't, then it will always be the value of the default language as a fallback.

You can however also use the `description` property of the product itself.

```
{{ page.product.description }}
```

This will always output the value for the current language and will not fallback to the default language's value. If there is no value for the current language it will be `null`.

Comment: Ok, but here is the thing: apparently we can't access the "current language" or the "default language" for "custom fields". Differently than fields like name/description, Shopware doesn't give us the possiblity to do the same with custom fields... or does it? If so, how?